# Insert statement doesn't insert more than one row into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is part of a project of student library.

There are 2 tables: `alerts` and `borrows`.

`borrows` contains `studentID`, `bookID` and `date of borrowing`.

`alerts` indicates which student is overdue with how many books.

The code is supposed to insert a row for each student who's overdue and counts how many books are overdue.

```
Est_Return_Date = return_date + 30

insert into dbo.Alert (studentID, AlertCount)
    values ((select distinct (studentID )from dbo.Borrows
        where Est_Return_Date < GETDATE()
        and return_date is null),
        (select count( studentID) from dbo.Borrows
        where Est_Return_Date < GETDATE()
        and return_date is null ))
```

Comment: The count will ALWAYS return one value. And probably the other select is also returning one value, that's your problem. You have the wrong query

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `GROUP BY` instead of subqueries, what you want is the result per studentId, so `GROUP BY` that and `COUNT` the rows with an alert;

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Alert (studentID, AlertCount)
SELECT studentID,COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Borrows
WHERE Est_Return_Date < GETDATE()
AND return_date is NULL
GROUP BY studentID;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e03d/5).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 insert into dbo.Alert (studentID, AlertCount)
select studentId, count(*) as AlertCount from dbo.Borrows  where Est_Return_Date < GETDATE()
        and return_date is null group by studentId
```

Considering what you want to do, your query will Always insert 1 value - The count is returning the count of total students, and probably your another select is also returning one value only. This query will group by student, and make a count of total books of the other table, when is overdue

Read something about group by [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx). If it's MySQL works too.
Another page, with one example, is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)